# focus gained on other jtextfield than the one I left when panel left focus

Tags: java, swing, focus, jframe, jtextfield

the focus is in a jtextfield (the first)
I click somewhere else on the desktop (to make the frame loose its focus)
if I click on another jtextfield (the second), I want it gaining the focus without passing by the first one (which is not the case unfortunately).

This is what I obtain when clicking on the second jtextfield, coming from an other aplication :

```
windowGainedFocus
focus gained on first
mouse pressed on second
focus gained on second

import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowFocusListener;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class FocusIssue extends JFrame implements WindowFocusListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new FocusIssue().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public FocusIssue() {

        JTextField tf = new JTextField(10);
        tf.setName("first");
        tf.addFocusListener(new GFocusListener());
        tf.addMouseListener(new GMouseAdapter());

        getContentPane().add(tf, "North");

        tf = new JTextField(10);
        tf.addFocusListener(new GFocusListener());
        tf.addMouseListener(new GMouseAdapter());
        tf.setName("second");
        getContentPane().add(tf, "South");

        addWindowFocusListener(this);

        pack();
    }

    @Override
    public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("windowGainedFocus");
    }

    @Override
    public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("windowLostFocus");
    }

    public class GFocusListener extends FocusAdapter {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            System.out.println("focus gained on " + ((JComponent) e.getSource()).getName());
        }
    }

    public class GMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("mouse pressed on " + ((JComponent) e.getSource()).getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your goal/what are you trying to achieve with the `FocusAdapter`/`WindowFocusListener`s?

Comment: Examining the code more I believe this is the expected behaviour. Because if when we left the window the first textfield was in focus than when we come back by clicking on another filed the window is brought to focus (with the last component which was in focus) than executes the mouse click/focusGained call on the new component...

Comment: Yes I know this is the normal behaviour. The problem is that in my app, I am using a special jtextfield with a big blinking caret, and in this special context, it starts to blink (say 0.2seconds) in the first textfield, before going to the second. I want to avoid this visual efect.
In the other contexts (app recovering the focus by ALT+TAB for example), I want the last focused textfield to recover its focus normaly.

I thought I would have to consider the focusadapter/focuslistenerwindow, but eventualy maybe that won't be the solution.

Comment: Ok, I found a solution using a combination of mouseEntered, windowGainedFocus, and saving the last focused component on leaving the focus.